# React Native Camera not Appearing (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am building an app to record video using React Native and RNCamera. I've installed RNCamera with the commands: `npm install react-native-camera` and `pod install`; however, when my app runs, the camera (and the button I created to trigger the camera) do not show up. Here is where I declare my RNCamera:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          // permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
          // permissionDialogMessage={
          //   "We need your permission to use your phone camera"
          // }
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center"}}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.startRecording.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> RECORD </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
```

My startRecording() function is declared as follows:

```js
  startRecording = async () => {
    const options = { orientation: "landscapeRight"};
    this.setState({ recording: true });
    const { uri, codec = "mp4" } = await this.camera.recordAsync(options);
    console.log(uri)
  }
```

I also have the following lines in my Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) to upload files.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permission required</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permission required for microphone use</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Permission required for photo gallery</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo library usage</string>
```

Does anyone know how to get RNCamera to show up? I've tried to manually link it, too, but that did not work. Thank you!

***EDIT***
In my App.js file, I call my camera class as such: `<RecordVideo/>` but inside of a `<View>`. However, when I deleted the view tags, the camera started working. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you try real device?

Comment: Yes, the page loads but nothing appears--just a white screen.

Comment: try giving the view a flex value `style={{ flex: 1 }}`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!